# Why can't I edit the servlet name in web.xml?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I have gotten everything working for my class in which I am using Tomcat and Eclipse to write java servlets.  What I would like to know is why eclipse seems to give me problems when I try to edit the servlet-name in the web.xml file.  Does eclipse not allow you to edit this file?

I know that it automatically adjusts the file to include the servlets that you add to a project, but  can't I edit it manually?  I can go in and change the servlet-name, but then it doesn't work with the new servlet name. I can do this all manually without eclipse, and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been a while since the last time I developed a servlet but I think you should reference your servlet name in your servlet mapping.

This [link](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/servlet/tutorial/helloworld/index.xtp) might help you.

Comment: I feel silly now, I do have to change the name in the servlet definition in the web.xml AND the servlet-mapping definition too.  Those both have to have the same servlet-name.  Thanks for slapping me upside the head :)

Comment: Don't worry it happens to all of us... :)